# Can I build a working(ish) vacuum tube byte?

Tags: history, old-hardware-adaptation, vacuum-tube

This is a somewhat odd question. I teach a course on media history, and spend some time talking about digital data towards the end. I am interested in building a device to illustrate some basic ideas about digital data:

1. the binary character of digital data
2. some sense of how it is materially stored and represented
3. how binary data becomes recognizable/usable as, for instance, a numerical value, an ASCII character, part of an RGB value, through being interpreted by a variety of formats

So, imagine eight switches, each of which represents a bit—the unit as a whole represents a single byte. By manipulating the switches we change the value represented by the byte; this device could be connected to a screen or television, and the value (binary, hex, decimal, and perhaps ASCII) could be displayed on a screen. I could imagine putting together some LEDs, some cheap switches, and an Arduino or a Raspberry Pi to make such a device.

But, **ideally**, I'd like to use vintage parts, so that this device could not simply illustrate binary, but also provide at least a glimpse of the  ways that binary data has been physically represented. My general understanding is that in early computing, pre-solid state technology, a bit would represented by a single vacuum tube. Is there a feasible way to build a byte using vacuum tubes, whose value could be changed with electrical switches, and then have some sort of interface to connect it to a Pi (or something else) to read its value and output it to a screen?

I've seen, for instance, [this video](https://youtu.be/hQWcIkoqXwg?t=2m14s) with a device similar to what I'm interested in. I don't need it to be *as* authentic; I can use newer vacuum tubes. I could also use something that *isn't* a vacuum tube (I could use individual transistors for instance). I like the idea of vacuum tubes chiefly because it can help illustrate a longer history of computing technologies.

So, denizens of Stack Exchange, any ideas? Is this feasible?

Comment: This is rather broad.  There are any number of ways that you could do this.

Comment: @Chenmunka yes, it is, and usually I'd strongly vote for closing, but I would love to keep it as it's anways a nice to think how old techonlogy can be used for teaching. Especially since this involves common missconceptions.

Comment: I added some images and stuff to my answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Switching Tech**

1. **Tubes**

   I do not recommend to use them because you would need to deal with high voltage and heat dissipation which can be potentially dangerous especially in class (pupils do not act with self preservation in mind sometimes).

   [image: tube]
2. **Relays**

   Very nice alternative. Easy to understand (switch with electromagnet) using single low voltage (5V,12V,48V). They are still used and produced so you might have no problem obtaining them. My best bet would be to use the transparent ones where you can see the coil and switches... They natively provide functionality of **NOT**(`/`),**COPY**(`1`) gates and more of them can be combined into **AND**(&),**OR**(1),**NAND,NOR** gates easily in an understandable way even for people with almost no electric engineering knowledge. They usually have more than just single switch so in case of more complex logic circuits you do not need to add more relays per gate using the same input signal (unlike TTL) so the number of used relays is not proportional to number of logic gates (up to a point).

   The disadvantage is they are noisy (not an issue for low speeds and small number of relays) and current hungry (should prefer the low power ones) they will eat up significant amount of current so you need to have adequate power supply.

   [image: relay]
3. **Transistors**

   These are the best from performance and power consumption perspective but for your purpose they might not be as educational as the previous options. On the other hand with transistors you will need to add a lot of passive components to make hem work safely.
4. **Diodes**

   Yes even diodes are used for switching in some cases (See [DTL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diode%E2%80%93transistor_logic) technology) but unless **LED**s are used they might not be as educational too.
5. **Resistors**

   some gates are doable with passive component too like Wire OR ... might save you some active stuff... But not usable with power hungry switching like relays without amplification or serious heat problems.

**Storage**

1. **[flip/flop circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics))**

   usually contained with 2 switching parts looped together. They are booth either copy or negator gate. You might also add some diodes or other gates to decouple Read and Write signals.
2. **Ferrite memories**

   using magnetization hysteresis where used in computer in the past (not just tapes and mag strips there where also hybrid ICs for this too)
3. **Dynamic memory DRAM**

   It uses capacitance to store data where the medium can be anything even heat (not just electric charge)... but needs a refresh cycle to maintain the data storage time to time
4. **Mechanical memory**

   where the data is stores as mechanical state of some moving part like rotation angle of a shaft, or linear position or whatever ...

**Display**

1. **Numitron/Digitron**

   Old glow-tube style character or numeric or combined single digit/character display. There are two types one is segmented (like 7-segment) and the other is layered having one electrode layer per each supported alphanumeric character. If you use tubes than this is the way for display. But it is a tube so read the Tubes topic too.

   [image: digitron]
   [image: numitron]
   [[image: digitron[5]]
2. **7-Segment LED Display**

   you need a proper decoder to convert binary to hex/dec for proper 7-Segment display output (there are ICs for that) but can be done with KLO using switching gates (even with relays). These displays are still in use so you should have no problem obtaining it. If you want old look you can even use light bulbs organized in a similar manner instead.

   [image: 7-segment]

   Binary Coded Decimal **BCD** is your friend.

   [image: BCD to 7 segment decoder]
3. **LED**

   this is suitable for binary output of your Byte. Also you can use light bulbs instead. **LED**s are combinable with any of the switching technologies you just add proper resistor. On the other hand Light bulbs are power hungry and require power switching so you would need to adjust the final gates for them.
4. **VGA**

   You can use small [MCU to generate VGA signal directly](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/6055/6868) with your `BYTE` number (AVR32 like AT32UC3A is powerful enough for this task)
5. **PC**

   You can send the `BYTE` to **PC** and display it with simple app. You can use **RS232** or **USB** or even **LPT** (if proper drivers are added to enable access) but this would also require **MCU** usage.

If I where you I would chose low power **5V** or **12V** relays and 8 switches 2 x **7 segment display** and **BCD** 2x4 bit encoding. So you would have everything on single board with only single power supply requirement or even on battery power (for limited use) all the logic is doable with relays. You would need 16 for the memory and either 2x **BCD to 7 segment decoder** or do it on your own (but that would be quite a lot of relays) Interesting would be do one digit with IC and the other with relays to visually show what ICs and integration are for.

Btw may be using push buttons would be better than switches as the switches on it self are form of mechanical memory rendering your memory circuit needless. For example 8x set button and one reset for all bits.

Comment: There are several kinds of neon display devices.  I wouldn't really call a Digitron (Nixie) like you pictured above "seven-segment-like", though there do exist other seven-segment neon displays (e.g. the Numitron).  Such displays were very common in pinball machines until they were displaced by graphic displays.  On the subject of neon "trons", one of the most interesting is the "Dekatron", which combines counting and readout functions in a single tube that uses cleverly-shaped electrodes to act as a single-digit base-ten counter.  I would expect students would be fascinated by such things.

Comment: Brilliant answer. I assume you mention tubes first, as the OP mentions them specifically, but pedantically, it would be better to put relays first, since they predated tubes in (proto-) computers (a good part of the success of [Colossus at Bletchley Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossus_computer) was that it was (almost) all vacuum tubes instead of electromechanical).

Comment: @supercat yep you're right I did not find any segment like image on quick google search that one has layers of digits instead of segments.

Comment: @Spektre: The Digitron is a formed-character display.   If you want to find seven-segment ones, look up "Numitron".

Comment: @supercat I edited the topic a bit feel free to correct ... tubes are not my cup of tea.

Comment: @Spektre: I wonder what letters were available on each digit of the "SAMAnTHA" display?  My guess would be that at least some of them were designed to show units on some kind of multi-meter, but don't think siemens, tesla, and henry would be common units in such apparatus, and I'd think Hertz would put "Hz" together in one glass.

Comment: @supercat the only devices where I saw this tech used was clocks and old coin game consoles and even that was like 25+ years ago The characters used may be custom to target device. I can not find any image of the segmented characters (it was way more than just 7 segments) The samantha looks like layered I do not think there was too many characters  as each need own layer and insulation gap and the tubes are not that thick I think to fit in whole ASCII

Comment: @Spektre: There's no way such tubes would be able to support full alphanumeric, much less full ASCII.  I don't think I've heard of any with more than ten.  Formed-digit Nixie tubes used to be very common for numeric readouts, and segmented neon readouts were used in just about every pinball machine manufactured in the 1980s by anyone other than Gottlieb or Premiere (who used vacuum-fluorescent displays).

Answer (score 10):

Nice idea. I like it.

### Tubes et all.

> My general understanding is that in early computing, pre-solid state technology, a bit would represented by a single vacuum tube.

That would be a missconception to start with. A tube doesn't store anything. In 'tube based' computers, tubes (usually [triodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triode)) provide a `NOT` functionality, as `AND`/`OR` are made up of resistors and diodes.

But there where some specialized storage tubes, but different from what you imagine. One was the [Williams tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Williams_tube), basicly a CRT where dots could be read back. The other was the [Selectron tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selectron_tube). also using the same effects, but with a more sohisticated and adapted design. Both vanished soon for core memory.

Havin said that, regular tubes where of course used also to store bits - as part of a [Flipflop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_(electronics)) - but it always (*1) needs two triodes.  The first (documented) one would be the *Eccles–Jordan trigger circuit* (patent filed 1918).

Since double triodes - two triodes in one glas tube - are usually used, the impression may arise that only one tube is needed.

A tube based flipflop may look like this:

[image]

### The Display (Background)

> I could imagine putting together some LEDs, some cheap switches, and an Arduino or a Raspberry Pi to make such a device.

Naa, uncool.

> But, ideally, I'd like to use vintage parts, so that this device could not simply illustrate binary, but also provide at least a glimpse of the ways that binary data has been physically represented.

Yes, that's the real way :))

> Is there a feasible way to build a byte using vacuum tubes, whose value could be changed with electrical switches,

Yes, it is, and it isn't a lot of work.

> and then have some sort of interface to connect it to a Pi (or something else) to read its value and output it to a screen?

Naa, that'll kill the whole effort. I'd strongly suggest to keep complete free of modern computing/controlling parts. Otherwise the pupils may come up with the idea that it's faked anyway. No hidden (or visible) modern devices should be harmed when making this demonstrator :))

> I could also use something that isn't a vacuum tube (I could use individual transistors for instance). I like the idea of vacuum tubes chiefly because it can help illustrate a longer history of computing technologies.

As [Manassehkatz](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/4921/manassehkatz) already [pointed out](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/6450/6659), relays do make a great demonstrator. Here the students can see the bits physically switch. It's even possible to add mechanical markers to display the state of each bit - providing a way to read the data without any electronic support :))

### The Display (Suggestion)

Go with a set of [relays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relay) displaying your data - maybe 4 for a number, or 8 for a byte - configured as a latch holding the last input. To set new data have 4 (or 8) flip switches where any new data can be configured, and a button enabling these setting so be transferred into the latch.

This setup shows that the storage is real and not just the direct result of the switches (like light and lightswitch at home). Data can be changed as often as needed until it's transferred, and stored data won't change until a new transfer is initiated (button pressed).

LEDs can be used in conjunction with the relays and the switches to show each state independently and continuously.

As an addition (or alternative) a decimal input could be constructed (at least for the 4 bit/numeric version). Have 10 buttons (0..9) and a diode matrix to encode them as BCD. Here each switch would trigger the latch right away. Showing much functionality with next to no parts(*2).

In fact, with the numeric version you could use the saved 4 relays to store a second number - like whenever a new input gets stored in the first 4 relays, their content gets transferred to the second first - thus showing even data transfer between latches - and a simple input routine - in pure clear, clicking and moving hardware.

With sufficient contacts on your relays it would be rather easy to extend this with an adder function summing up both digits and displaying the result...

*... I'm not getting carried away on that, am I?*

**Long story short, relays are an extremely handy tool to explain the basics. And you'll be surprised how versatile a large enough bunch of switches is :))**

Oh, and one more thing: Relays allow you to build all of this using low voltage, like all 5V (or even below), so no danger as with tubes and neon lamps. Not to mention the way simpler power supply to be used (*3).

---

*1 - There are designs that can keep a bit with just one tube, but not for generic use

*2 -  And no bloaty Java libraries just to convert some input :))

*3 - With a small enough setup a standard USB wall-wart might be enough to supply the device.

Comment: This is a great response; thanks! I am convinced by you, and @manassehkatz, that relays are the way to go. I may not abandon an Arduino output completely, for ease though ;)

One point of clarification. So, in vacuum tube computers, a bit (in RAM< or a register, or similar) **does not** mean a vacuum tube; but *does* very likely mean a flipflip, which involves 2 triode tubes (which *may* be packaged together to appear as one glass "tube"). So when a tube-based computer operated on 8-bit memory, there were 8 flipflops representing that memory, correct?

Comment: @cforster If the 8-bit memory was implemented in tubes, then yes. But, particularly at levels beyond the "register" level, memory could be implemented in other ways, such as mercury delay lines, that have nothing to do with flip-flops.

Comment: @manassehkatz: Mercury delay lines are nasty because, well, mercury, but acoustic delay lines were actually pretty common inside a number of old calculator designs.

Comment: I wonder if anyone constructed vacuum tubes with internal connections that were optimized for computing applications?  For example, a tube with three anodes around a common cathode, where anodes #1 and #2 had a grid attached to cathode #3, and anode #3 had a grid attached to cathode #2, and each anode also had a separate grid, could act as an addressable memory bit with seven non-filament connections.  Do you know if such things were ever done?

Comment: There have been zillions of very special tubes over the years, so maybe even variations that would have reduced the amount of seperate tubes needed for computing. But I doubt that. Unlike the general impression tells, tubes wheren't the main parts in 'tube' computers - just the most easy to tell ones. But more important, the age of tube computers did last not even a decade. During that time improvements in modularization (like IBM did) as well as more reliable diodes (and tubes) and smaler resistors where more relevant to create reliable and cheaper computers than more complex tubes.

Comment: @Raffzahn: I guess that once magnetic cores were invented, they were probably more practical than any kind of storage using a vacuum or gas-filled tube with lots of fiddly metal bits inside.  The display/storage approach I'd still think would be cool, though, would be a addressable neon bitmap display tube where each row would have a wire and each column would be a "comb" with moderate-resistance tines and a lower-resistance spine.  I don't know that electronically reading such a memory would be practical, but writing it probably wouldn't be too bad.  Any idea how well that could work?

Comment: @supercat Not realy, as it still needed registers and other fast memory cells. And yes, Neon Lamp Memory is a neat idea, but for computing not realy useful. for one, the controlling requires high voltage and to multiplex diodeds sufficient for this voltage would be needed. But second, and more important, they max out around 15-20 kHz switching rate. To keep within a reliable range, a neon based memory would have to operate around 1 milli (!) second write time (reading might be way faster). Cool for some experiments, but way too slow even for early machines.

Comment: @Raffzahn: For general-purpose memory, that would indeed be way too slow, but for some kinds of pixel-based displays that might not be too bad if the host could render part of the display and then recycle the backing store while the image remained.  A CRT requires a backing store for as long as the image will remain displayed, and storage tubes generally don't allow any kind of addressable erase operation.  I don't know how finely one could make the components for a neon display storage tube, but it would seem like there might have been some narrow niche somewhere.

Comment: @supercat I know no common neon lamps with less than 8mm diameter. They are also not very bright as they uses 'stick' electrodes. (Somewhat) brighter, 'dish' shaped ones have a diameter of 10mm. So if at all, you get some 2 dpi :)) Which means the minimum distance to view a picture qould be like 3-6m. A simple 256x256 display would require 65536 sockets, resistors and lamps - not to mention the effort for addressing and so on. Using a storage tube would be a fraction thereof, while offering an incredible higher resolution. Not to mention that neiter backstorage nor readback is something needed

Comment: @Raffzahn: Using discrete lamps for a grid-based display would likely not work very well.  On the other hand, adjusting the design of what would otherwise be a scanning neon dot matrix display (like the ones used on pinball machines) to allow storage would merely require adding a certain amount of resistance between each column bus and the point that current leaves it.

Comment: @Raffzahn: The disadvantage of storage tubes is that the ones I've seen generally lack any kind of localized erase function; the only way to erase anything from the screen is to flash and blank the entire screen, and then redraw everything--an operation that in many cases will take many seconds.

Comment: @supercat A scanning dislay is for the time of tube computers way out of scope - even when done mechanical. Remember your starting point was that a neon lamp keepps its 'value' as a memory cell. A scanning display is not using that advantage and thus not better than an array of lamps. Making new devices is also out of scope. Next, why do you need erasing parts of a picture? Remember the time of development. At that stage we're happy to get a high resolution picture. Last but not least, **this is way off the question asked**. Maybe good for an idle discussion board, but not RC. Don't you agree?

Answer (score 9):

My suggestion would be to use relays. Still readily available, and while you wouldn't be using vintage parts, there were definitely some computers built with relays. Can't handle as high speed as well as good vacuum tubes, but that isn't an issue here. The good part is that even if you can't see much - which will depend on the relay, you can **hear** every click. Audible feedback for every bit change.

Comment: Adding audio output to a class on media history is a definite bonus

Comment: Vacuum tubes seem to be making a comeback.  While very hard to find for awhile, the last few hamfests I've been to offered huge selections.

Comment: With relays you won't have to deal with the high voltage power for vacuum tubes, and the heat either.

Answer (score 4):

I'm personally intrigued by the use of neon lamps for storage, and although neon logic wasn't employed for anything particularly complicated back in the day, this could be a good application for it.  A neon lamp will behave as a sort of switch that will not conduct until a certain voltage is applied, but once it does it will continue to conduct as long as a certain minimum current is allowed through.  An oscillator can be constructed easily using a neon bulb, 1-3 resistors, and a capacitor.  Adding additional resistors and capacitors will make it possible to produce things like counters and other forms of logic without any other kind of switching device.

While the switching characteristics of neon lamps aren't ideal for practical logic, they would offer an advantage for your scenario: their operation is nicely visible.  Relays could also work, and would have some other advantages, but most relays don't offer the same nice visual.  Perhaps the ideal would be to combine relay logic and neon logic.  I'm not sure whether such a thing could be made reliable without having to tweak every individual component,  but I think it would be possible to construct a neon-based RAM by placing lamps, each with a series resistor, on a grid.

Idle rows would sit at about 30 volts, and idle columns at about 60.  To read a row, drive it to 0 volts and sense which columns have an increase in current (that would be the part I'm least certain about).  To set clear a row, raise it to 60 volts.  Then to set some bits in a row, drive it to 0 volts while driving some columns to 90 volts.

Even if you couldn't manage to read anything from the neon storage arrangement, it might still be interesting as a write-only display device.  If you had an assembly with e.g. an 4x4 or 8x8 grid, a power supply input, and resistors to handle the idle row/column currents, along with a 10-pin or 20-pin connector to attach a controller board, you could demonstrate that the lights could hold their state even with the controller board disconnected.

Comment: To add to the fun, neon lamps are light sensitive: exposure to bright light lowers the voltage at which they conduct. And a bank of them will interact (to a small degree).

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zOlI1_i2HwQ) about the restoration of a module with 8 vacuum tubes that looks very similar to the one in your video, but is a key debouncer. Details [here](http://www.righto.com/2018/01/examining-1954-ibm-mainframes-pluggable.html) and [here](http://www.righto.com/2018/01/ibm-mainframe-tube-module-part-ii.html).

It's pretty unlikely that the module shown in your video is really "8 bits", unless the mainframe had internal registers that really used vacuum tubes instead of something else. Usually, the vacuum tubes were used for logic.

That said, "8 bits" is an abstract concept: 8 switches already represent 8 bits, no other parts needed.

If you want to add some impressive-looking electronics, you could consider adding a 9th switch to store the value of the switches, this is called a [D-Latch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flop_%28electronics%29#Gated_D_latch) or D-Flip-Flop. You can implement one with vacuum tubes, relays, transistors, and it's not that difficult to do. So, certainly feasible.

The details of that are probably better suited to an electronics forum than here, though.

Comment: Vacuum tubes would've been used for logic in the form registers and latches that could hold data just like transistors on ICs do today.

Comment: Thanks for the video. It also led me to [this series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F__TroRudww) on relay computers, which is proving *really* helpful.

Comment: @RossRidge: The point I was trying to make is that while you certainly *can* use vacuum tubes to implement registers, it's too expensive to do so, which is why early vacuum tube computers used e.g. short mercury delay lines even for the registers.

Answer (score 1):

Have done so long ago (RS F/F for a demonstration), *without* introducing brutal voltages, have lost the schematics :(

What I remember is that I used an E88CC (6DJ8), with either 12V or 24V as an anode voltage and 6.3V as both heater and negative bias. Standard flip flop circuit. This was not capable of driving a standard LED directly (and low current LEDs weren't at hand), so a lamp driver had to be hidden in the set up.

You will need one tube per bit - tubes with more than two triode or higher order systems per bulb are rare (unless you count in VFD displays - these are actually vacuum tube arrays, though very low gain).

If running such low voltages with vacuum tubes, there might be a need to use variable resistors and tune the operating points just right.

There were special vacuum tubes for low voltage use: So called space charge tubes, and later some optimized designs for car radio use. Both are likely too rare for such a project.

...

EDIT: non-multiplexed VFD displays might actually make the perfect indicator for your bytes - they need very low drive currents, and could share a, say, +30V or +48V environment with your tubes very comfortably. Unlike nixies, they do come in 7 segment styles and need no really lethal voltages - decoding circuitry could be tricky though :)

Comment: Conversion of a one-hot signal to a seven-segment readout could be done fairly easily with 50 semiconductor diodes.  Selenium diodes might need to be doubled up for such purposes (Wiki says they were good for about 25 volts each) but even in the 1960s that would have been about $1 worth of diodes.  Nowadays of course one would use silicon diodes, but the technique would have been practical (using selenium diodes) even when silicon ones were expensive.

Comment: Germanium diodes were perfectly present during most of the vacuum tube era, and there were 90V Vrr capable types...

Comment: How cheap were germanium diodes?  The Wiki page on selenium rectifiers suggested that single unit diodes used for logic were less than $0.01 each which would seem like a hard price to beat.

Comment: Selenium diodes were used together with relays in telephone exchange logic a lot, less so with vacuum tubes.... maybe they were slow? Certainly, if you plan to experiment with selenium diodes, there are a few hazards to be aware of. If they are "open faced" designs with the rectifier element exposed, wash your hands after touching them, there are cadmium compounds in there. Also, never give them serious overcurrent, they are quick to fail catastrophically and known to emit nasty and toxic smoke when burning up.

Answer (score 0):

At one time I had several dozen vacuum tube flip flops. I have no idea of their original origin or use. They used 12AX7 tubes (a dual triode) and were packaged in a die-cast housing with an octal plug on the bottom so that the entire circuit could be easily replaced.
Nearly all digital circuitry I was involved with during the late 60's and early 70's involved counting and displaying pulses from nuclear counters. The most popular (and simplest) used the aforementioned dekatron tubes that combined counting and display functions in a single device; no help for your use, but in fact their circuitry DID require a single flip-flop.
I like the idea of using relays, but would suggest that you use individual incandescent light bulbs as displays for historic accuracy and "coolness". LED's didn't exist alongside tubes, and were initially expensive. Also, don't get hung up on binary or byte oriented operation. Many of the devices of the day used base 10 counting/computing because the logic involved in converting from binary was prohibitive. (Hence the dekatron, which counted 0 to 9, and produced a "carry" pulse on the 9 to 0 transition.)

Comment: The logic to convert from binary to decimal isn't particularly expensive if one doesn't need to do the conversion particularly quickly.  I think the bigger issues are that (1) it was useful to display multiple values simultaneously, and displaying the contents of registers that could also partake in computations was nicer than having to store converted values in addition to the ones used for computation; (2) computing the product of two fractions that use a power-of-ten base will require a power-of-ten division; doing *that* is trivial in decimal, but expensive in binary.

Comment: Although the use of fractions with a power-of-two base is considered normal today, I don't think people back then would have liked the weird rounding behaviors it introduces, especially since they make it harder to hand-check the machine's work.

Comment: For example, on a system that uses 8.8 decimal fixed-point math, computations of the form (a/b)*c would be processed with a worst-case error of c/200000000.  A system that used 32.32 binary fixed-point math would have a worst-case error that's less than 5% of that.  On the other hand, when asked to compute (1/3)*10000000 the former system would yield 3333333.300000000; not accurate, but easily verifiable as being computed as specified.  The computation using 32.32 binary format would yield 3333333.332557231, which is mathematically more accurate, but harder to verify.

Comment: You are both missing one important thing. ANY kind of calculation was out of the question with the available tech. Draw me a schematic of a binary to decimal converter using only vacuum tubes and we will talk. Yes, IC's existed, but only Uncle Sam was using them. Industrial use was a few years down the road.

Comment: The Atanasoff-Berry Computer used binary arithmetic for all its calculations but when fed the proper programming cards could convert decimal numbers to binary or vice versa.  Conversion of arbitrary numbers stored in shift registers or delay lines requires an essentially fixed amount of hardware, aside from the storage for the numbers and a counter to say when the conversion is complete.  Basically, all one needs for BCD to decimal conversion is a long "straight" shift register and a 3-bit circuit that outputs N if N<5 or its control is inactive, and N-5 otherwise.

Comment: Use that along with the delay line to repeatedly divide the BCD number by 2, placing the bits into a binary register LSB first.  Converting binary to BCD is a little harder, but still not too bad.  The conceptually simplest approach is to use a BCD register that can compute 2N or 2N+1 based on a carry input, and that generates a carry output.  Use that to process each digit in little-endian order, except that every time one is processing the first digit the carry should be taken from the binary number, in big-endian order.  Processing a 20-digit BCD number into binary would may take...

Comment: ...5000+ cycles, but if numbers are being read mechanically from punched cards, that amount of time might not be too bad compared with the time required to feed the next card.